# How to understand logging formatter?

Tags: python, logging

To Python Experts:

I'm new to programming and learning logging python package.

According to logging document, I set the format of my logging message as follows:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

Here is the output of logging message:

```
2016-08-09 19:57:08,363 - DEBUG -             A   B
2016-01-31  0  12
2016-02-29 -1  12
```

How to make A B (the column names of the datafram) to the next line?:

Also, would you please help me understand %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s? why put % before bracket and s after bracket?

```
2016-08-09 19:57:08,363 - DEBUG -  
                A   B
    2016-01-31  0  12
    2016-02-29 -1  12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:

Just add an extra newline to your call of `logging.debug`:

For example, if your logger is called `logger`, and you are logging the message through `logging.debug(msg)`, you can call `logging.debug('\n' + msg`) to move the message onto the newline.

As for the format: the `%` indicates that the upcoming text should be parsed as a format specifier. The parentheses, `()`, surround the name of the specifier, and the trailing `s` converts the input data into a string. See: [difference between `str.format` and `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format).

So, `%(name)s` allows you to specify `name` which will be converted to a string. The different names, `asctime`, `levelname`, `message` are specified by the logging framework.

Comment: Thanks. What if my msg is a DataFrame? df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, -1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1], 'B': [12, 12, 14, 15, 14, 16, 200]})   logging.debug('\n'+ df) doesn't work..@Rushy Panchal

Comment: @Lisa You can try using `str(df)`, which will convert it to a string first. However, the representation of that is defined by the DataFrame which may not be what you want.